# My app needs to read information from sqlite databases but heroku does not allow sqlite at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

My Ruby on Rails webapp allows for users to upload an sqlite database in order to export information from that database in a certain format.
Locally everything works fine but I can't deploy it to heroku as I am using the sqlite gem. Heroku doesn't allow it even tho I use postgres for the app itself as configured in the database.yml.

Before I move everything to another PaaS I'd like to know are there any other ways to access the information in the sqlite DB without using the sqlite gem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't use SQLite on Heroku (and I discourage you to use it in any production environment).

When deploying to Heroku the database.yml file gets replaced. Reading from the docs:

> When an application is deployed, the build phase configures the underlying Rack or Rails application to use the provisioned database if a config directory exists, and a RAILS_ENV or RACK_ENV environment variable is present. Under these conditions, a database.yml file will be created . If a database.yml file already exists, it will be replaced. The database.yml file is created as Ruby code that dynamically creates its output by parsing the DATABASE_URL environment variable.

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior

If you want to use PostreSQL in Heroku, just put the needed gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

Comment: The usecase of my app is that users upload an sqlite database and my app reads information from that database and exports it in a certain format. I don't think I can use postgres for that. Can postgres read sqlite db files?